# jQuery: execute method from string

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to call methods by their name in jQuery? For example:

```
var condition = true;
$('div').execute(condition ? 'show':'hide');
```

Comment: What is it you are trying to do? It may be that there is a better solution _not_ involving dictionary based access of methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the `[]`notation to access properties of the jQuery object (rather than literal ones using `.`):

```
$('div')[condition ? 'show' : 'hide']();
```

You can also do:

```
$('div').toggle(condition);
```

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

http://www.jibbering.com/faq/faq_notes/square_brackets.html

**Edit:** Just in case you prefer your own style of coding, you could add this:

```
$.fn.execute = function(a) {
    return this[a].apply(this, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
```

Then you can do like:

```
$('div').execute(condition ? 'show' : 'hide');
```

or

```
$('div').execute(condition ? 'keydown' : 'keyup', function() {...});
```

Comment: @Dziamid: I use `.toggle` mostly, because it's clearer to read.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript objects are basically dictionaries.

```
var condition = true;
$('div')[condition ? 'show':'hide']();
```